# Getting Error "Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'" when Syncing Build.Gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

[image: Error after resolution][image: project is staymax][image: 2 build.gradle files that i am working on]To add V4 support libraries to android studio, i followed this document:https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-without-res but I get an error. Here is what i did

1. SDK manager> Installed Android Support Library and Android Repository.
2. Go to Build.Gradle and added the line as given in the dcoument. Build.Gradle now looks like this:

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    dependencies {

        compile "com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+"
    }
}

}
```

Then, I get a popup that suggest that I sync gradle. When i sync Gradle, i get this error:

Error:(20, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'
Possible causes:

The project 'staymax' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

Am i missing any step? Please suggest.

Build.Gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 20
buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.appt.shreyabisht.staymax"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: Generally you declare dependencies on an individual module, rather than in the top level build file. Are you sure you want to add this to every module in your project?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In almost all cases, your dependencies should be put into the individual module's build.gradle files rather than at the top most level build.gradle file. In your case, that means the dependency should be added to the `app` module's build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+"
}
```

And you should remove the entire `allprojects` part of the top level build.gradle.

Comment: "In almost all cases, your dependencies should be put into the individual module's build.gradle files rather than at the top most level build.gradle file."

Comment: I have two build.gradlevfiles under Gradle Scripts. One is build.gradle(app) and other is build.gradle(staymax). Staymax is the project i am working on and I assumed that build.gradle was present by default. If you mean that I need to update a gradle file which is specific to the module that im working on ( I translate that as the test project i am working on ) ,  then i should be making changes to build.gradle(staymax) and not build.gradle(app). I will add a screenshot to make more sense of all this. Thanks.

Comment: staymax is the top most level build.gradle file (hence why the comment on the top of the file is `// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.` - `app` is the build.gradle for your app itself and is where you want to do everything in.

Comment: ok so what i understand now is . 1. build.grable(staymax) is the top most level and i should remove the entire allprojects{} from it.                    2. I have another build.gradle(app) which is individual module's build.gradle and i should edit the dependencies{} to  dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+"
}                                                                                  Did i get it right?

Comment: Good God!!! Thank you!!!!!!!                                                 So I did all that and it synched alright. Although its did say that "this support library should not use a lower version(18) than the targetversion(20) SDk."  Is this still ok or do i need to make any changes?

Comment: Changing your `18` to `20` is definitely a good idea, although you might consider also updating your target SDK version and support library to the latest: `21` to take advantage of the Android 5.0 Material Design support added in [AppCompat v21](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) - if you are following tutorials though, they are probably still using 20 though.

Comment: changed to 20. synced. and yes on that. Following tutorials, so ill just keep it 20 for a few test projects. Thank you thank you thank you for not just throwing the solution but also doing a little bit of explaining. Thank you . I will move on to new world of errors now.

Comment: soon after we resolved this problem, I went on to create new java files but i found that my older xmls were not sort of corrupted. When i clicked on design, i got errors like missing styles. Whats more is that android wont recognize the string that i had already added in the string resource. I was wondering if it has got anything to do with the changes we made in the build.gradle. I ran the project few hours ago and i was running. I am attaching a snapshot too.

Comment: could it be because i changed to 20? In the screenshot i can see im working on material design now ( the buttons resemble the one in android L)

Comment: Some of the helper methods such as adding a new activity will automatically include the latest version of the support libraries (which require compiling against the latest SDKs) - there's no harm in always compiling against the latest, but look through your dependencies for any version 21s and change them to 20s as a short term solution

Answer (score 12):

I have found that when I add an `applicationSuffix` or `versionNameSuffix` through the IDE menu (Build > Edit Build Types), it changes the dependencies section of my app build.gradle **from this**:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.json:json:20140107'

    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}" 
    compile "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}" 
    compile "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:${supportLibVersion}" // VectorDrawableCompat
    compile "com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:${supportLibVersion}" // AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat
}
```

**to this**:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.json:json:20140107'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}" compile "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}" compile "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:${supportLibVersion}"
    // VectorDrawableCompat
    compile "com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:${supportLibVersion}"
    // AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat
}
```

I don't know why, but it combines the first three "compile" lines into one line, and moves the two comments (to the next line in each case).

I solved the problem by editing the app build.gradle and putting each "compile" statement onto its own line.

Comment: Thank you so much, I resolved thanks to your tip. I don't know why AS decided to reformat the gradle file but it broke totally my project build. Now is ok :-)

Comment: Hey thank you that bloody IDE combined two lines in one in my case.

Comment: It literally did this with 9 consecutive lines in my build.gradle. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Thank you! After 2 hours trying to understand what was going on, found you post. AS... today was very annoying!

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

1. Exit Android Studio.
2. Remove `<home folder>/.gradle` folder.
3. Relaunch Android studio and let it load all gradle modules again.

P.S.: Mine was a fresh project so I removed the project as well and created a new one, so there were no old gradle references from the project

Answer (score 2):

In my case, there are 2 build.gradle file in my project (it auto create by android studio when create new project)

**Just move the compile line to another one is solve my problem**

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 different `build.gradle` (sometimes more depending on you)

Only one of them is your app's gradle, then the other one is project's gradle.

If you put your dependencies project's gradle you can get error : `Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'`

Put your dependencies in app's `build.gradle` then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

**Hi everyone**  for me it was a "couple days consuming job" to make my app run in Android Studio . Finally I found that very simple way of it .

1. Create **libs** folder under src/main/java/ it is App/java/libs in left pane .
2. Copy and paste all your external jars into here.
3. Goto left pane  and right click on your App then click **Open Module Settings**
4. Then Project Structure window will appear .
5. Then move to Dependencies tab .
6. Final Step : Add all your jars located in App/java/libs (You will find them in src/main/java/libs) one by one .

**That is all** Enjoy it.

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the method.

```
//DELETE THIS LINES:
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'
}
```

Try to compile again. It should work now.

Source : https://medium.com/@marcuspereira/solving-the-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-android-in-android-studio-6e5ab499bd3#.u1lxecq41

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, and the bug is my build.gradle of application level has dependencies of my submodules. Means

```
dependencies {
   compile project(':library')
  compile project(':MPChartLib')
}
```

I have just remove the two line inside the dependencies braces and it is able to start syncing.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting **.gradle** in my project folder did the job for me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a `settings.gradle` file in your project. Adding that solved the problem of `Error:Gradle DSL method not found: 'minSdkVersion()'` for me.