# gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()' persisting error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

This is what my gradle file looks like http://codeshare.io/RWMpl , its throwing a small error saying:

gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()' .

```
My gradle file : 

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'org.ektorp:org.ektorp:1.4.2'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

I followed the advice on **[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27156428/getting-error-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-compile-when-syncing-build-grad)** thread(see the accepted answer) , but i still get the following error:

> gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'.

Why ?

Comment: check if you have an android section in your top level build.gradle file

Comment: @Lal `andrid section` , like whats a android section . sorry i'am hving a blonde day .

Comment: @comrade ! are u a communist ? just out of curiosity !

Comment: usually there is a top build.gradle and a project build.gradle. The screenshot that you shared was of your  project build.gradle. so please check in your top build.gradle whether there is a block with name android.

Comment: Did you find out the top build.gradle file ? @Alexander

Comment: @Lal yes i have two gradle files , one is `build.gradle(Project: Button)` , the other is `build.gradle(Module: app)` , which one is top and which one is project ? which one do i need to add my dependencies to ?

Comment: yes..project build.gradle file..

Comment: remove android block from it and you'll get rid of the error.

Comment: @Lal compiles fine now , see my gradle file http://codeshare.io/5GjrJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You using a wrong gradle file. Check for `build.gradle(Module:yourmodulename)`, this is where you have to update.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, there is a Project `build.gradle` and a Module `build.gradle`.

The screenshot that you shared was of your Module `build.gradle`.

This error seems to me as, you have an android block in your Project `build.gradle` file.

**Remove android block from Project `build.gradle`** and the app will compile fine..

Comment: the one i name currently sharing is of module , so basically you mean remove that entire android block ? why ? for what purpose is it anyway ?

Comment: no no..i was saying, you should remove android block from your project build.gradle file, not from module build.gradle