# (Error 39, 0) Gradle method note found: 'compile()'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I get the following error: Error(39, 0) Gradle method note found: 'compile()'

[This is the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sahQj.png)

the following solutions don't seem to work:

[Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27617687/gradle-dsl-method-not-found-compile)

[gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()' persisting error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31874818/gradle-dsl-method-not-found-compile-persisting-error)

Here is my entire gradle.build file

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
    } 

    allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    }
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.audacityit.finder"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    apply plugin: 'maven'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.8.0'
}
```

Where exactly could I be going wrong?

Comment: use one `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.8.0'` & `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'`

Comment: set `compileSdkVersion 23` &  `targetSdkVersion 23`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Thanks, it works fine now

Answer (score 1):

At first you need to upgrade your `compileSdkVersion`  version & `targetSdkVersion` version .

```
compileSdkVersion 23 
targetSdkVersion 23
```

Finally

```
 android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.audacityit.finder"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```