# Gradle sync failed: Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1]

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am new to Android App Development. I am trying to create an Android app using TabLayout and have added the following dependencies in the build.gradle file.

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'


 }
```

But on running the App, I am getting build error as follows

> Error:(27, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'
>   Possible causes:
>
> The project 'MyFirstapp' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
>   Open Gradle wrapper file
>
> The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
>   Apply Gradle plugin

Any suggestions on why this problem is there. I get an option to install Plugin from Android Studio but I don't know which plugin to install.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27156428/getting-error-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-compile-when-syncing-build-grad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you are adding dependencies to the wrong build.gradle.

Try doing this:
In your first build.gradle replace the dependencies with this

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
}
```

and replace dependencies in build.gradle(Module:app) (2nd build.gradle file) with this

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem. I can't find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1 . Please help me: http://i.imgur.com/cqPtiSg.png