# Android : com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.7 gives build errors

Tags: java, android, google-maps, time, geocode

I tried to use Google Map Service by using com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.7 version.

After adding `complie 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.7'`to **build.gradle(Module: app)**, I tried to sync the project.

Then I got following errors in **Messages Gradle Sync**,

```
D:\Solutions\Security\app\build.gradle
Error:(26, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'complie()'

Possible causes:The project 'AIGSecurity' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
Upgrade plugin to version 2.3.2 and sync project
The project 'Security' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file
The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin
```

And This is my build.gradle(Module: app) file,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "solutions.com.security"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    complie 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.7'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4'
    compile 'com.auth0.android:jwtdecode:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:+'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Is there any way to fix this issue ?

Comment: Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27156428/getting-error-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-compile-when-syncing-build-grad)

Comment: @user7790438 : I read it but it didn't provide any solution to me. Any other ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you misspelled compile

```
complie 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.7'
```

to

```
compile 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.20'
```